# How to make if statement

Tags: shell, mkdir, cd

I need to check creating and changing dir for the new directory and print error ion fail someone from them like the following:

```
[ mkdir tmp && cd tmp ] || echo "error"
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
[: missing `]'
```

Comment: If `mkdir` fails it will print an error message.  Your echo is redundant, and writing to the wrong place.  Error messages belong on stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&&` is not allowed inside the brackets of a `test` command, so the missing `]` is the one that `bash` believes should be between `tmp` and `&&`.

A correct form of your command would be

```
mkdir tmp && cd temp || echo "error"
```

If `mkdir` fails, (or `cd` fails after `mkdir` succeeds), then execute the `echo`. No `test`/`[` command is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ -d tmp ] || mkdir tmp
```

Is probably what you are looking for. This checks for the existence of the directory then creates it if it does not exist.

```
[ -d tmp ] || mkdir tmp || echo "failure"
```

displays a message if the mkdir fails.

Answer (score 0):

or the more verbose but clearer version:

```
if [ ! -d temp ] # if there is no directory
then
     mkdir temp
fi
```